# Query automatically getting changed

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am facing a little problem. I am running a query with Like operator. But the problem is that the codeigniter is replacing '% character automatically. For example this is my code...

```
$where = "resume_id = '" . $resume_exist[0]['resume_id'] . "' AND finish_date LIKE '%" . $project_year . "%'";
```

Logically when I select some value for the $project_year it should be executed like

```
$where = "resume_id = '123' AND finish_date LIKE '%2013%'";
```

where as when I printed the query, this is something that is being executed

```
resume_id = '123' AND finish_date LIKE ' 13%'
```

You see that %20 is getting replaced with a space...

Please help that how can I correct this query.

Thanks and waiting...

Comment: "Printed the query" means what?

Comment: Do an echo for $project_year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...Actually %20 was being converted to space character...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$where = "resume_id = '" . $resume_exist[0]['resume_id'] . "' AND DATE_FORMAT(finish_date,'%Y') = '" . $project_year . "'";
```

Comment: no it does not work for me...actually i got this error before as well..it has nothing to do with date format as far as I think....

Comment: logically this is correct I think. finish_date LIKE '%2013%' = DATE_FORMAT(finish_date,'%Y') = '2013'. Why you think this is not work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution to bypass that situation.

Change your query to
`$where = "resume_id = ? AND finish_date LIKE ?";` and then when you call the query function, do the following:
`$this->db->query($query_start.$where.$query_end, array($resume_exist[0]['resume_id'], "%$project_year%"));` I'm assuming you have the starting of the query stored in `$query_start` and the ending of the query stored in `$query_end`